# How to transform this XML file into a "tibble"?

Tags: r, xml, tidyverse, rvest, xml2

I want to change this XML file
https://elections.interieur.gouv.fr/telechargements/MUNICIPALES2020/candidatureT1/001/C1001.xml
into a "tibble" (or a data.frame) with the following column names :

```
Type Annee CodDpt CodMinDpt LibDpt CodSubCom LibSubCom TypCom PopSubCom ModeScrutin NbSAP EPCI NbSapEpci NbCandidatsMaj NumListe CodNuaListe NomListe LibLisExt NumOrdCand NomPsn PrePsn CivilitePsn TeteListe CandidatEPCI
```

I tried :

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)
x <- read_xml("https://elections.interieur.gouv.fr/telechargements/MUNICIPALES2020/candidatureT1/001/C1001.xml")
tmp <- x %>% 
  xml_find_all('//Commune') %>%  
  map_df(~flatten(c(xml_attrs(.x), 
                    map(xml_children(.x), 
                        ~set_names(as.list(xml_text(.x)), xml_name(.x)))))) %>%
  type_convert()
```

but it does not produce what I'm expecting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there are quite a bit of nuances across the elements and two different sets of candidate elements (*CandidMaj* and *Candid*), consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/all/), the special purpose language to transform XML files, to flatten original nested XML. With this approach, you avoid doing all the work on procedural end in R. Then, bind the resulting flattened XML to needed data frame:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl file, a special .xml file)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/Election">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::CandidatMaj|descendant::Candidat"/>
     </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="CandidatMaj">
     <Candidat>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Election/Scrutin/*"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Departement/*[name() != 'Communes']"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Commune/*[name() != 'CandidatsMaj']"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::CandidatsMaj/*[name() != 'ListeCandidatsMaj']"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     </Candidat>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="Candidat">
     <Candidat>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Election/Scrutin/*"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Departement/*[name() != 'Communes']"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Commune/*[name() != 'Listes']"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::Liste/*[name() != 'CandidatsListe']"/>
       <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
     </Candidat>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**R**

```
library(xml2)
library(xslt)
library(dplyr)

# PARSE XML AND XSLT
doc <- read_xml('https://elections.interieur.gouv.fr/telechargements/MUNICIPALES2020/candidatureT1/001/C1001.xml')
style <- read_xml('/path/to/Script.xsl', package = "xslt")

# TRANSFORM INPUT INTO OUTPUT
new_xml <- xslt::xml_xslt(doc, style)

# BUILD DATA FRAME LIST
df_list <- lapply(xml_find_all(new_xml, 'Candidat'), function(x) { 
   vals <- xml_children(x)
   setNames(data.frame(t(xml_text(vals)), stringsAsFactors = FALSE), xml_name(vals))
})

# ROW BIND ALL DF
final_df <- bind_rows(df_list)
```

Comment: Thank you ! ... but I could not manage to make it work (...loooong period of computing and then R crashes...)

Comment: this line `new_xml <- xslt::xml_xslt(doc, style)`

Comment: Please see [slight update](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60696637/revisions) in XSLT. My apologies, previous XSLT was pulling from *Departement* tag recursively on itself. This should run much faster. No change to R code.

Comment: Thank you ! it is perfect. (It was a recursive curse indeed)

Answer (score 1):

I did manage to create this ugly code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(xml2)
library(rvest)

x <- read_xml("https://elections.interieur.gouv.fr/telechargements/MUNICIPALES2020/candidatureT1/001/C1001.xml")

x <- x %>% xml_find_all('//Commune')
x <- as_list(x)
tbl <- tibble(Communes=x)

communes <- tbl %>% unnest_wider(Communes) %>%
  unnest_longer(CodSubCom) %>%
  unnest_longer(LibSubCom) %>%
  unnest_longer(TypCom) %>%
  unnest_longer(PopSubCom) %>%
  unnest_longer(ModeScrutin) %>%
  unnest_longer(NbSAP) %>%
  unnest_longer(EPCI) %>%
  unnest_longer(NbSapEpci) %>% 
  hoist(CandidatsMaj,NbCandidatsMaj="NbCandidatsMaj") %>% unnest_longer(NbCandidatsMaj) %>%
  hoist(CandidatsMaj,NbSapMajRestant="NbSapMajRestant") %>% unnest_longer(NbSapMajRestant) %>%
  hoist(CandidatsMaj,candidats=c("ListeCandidatsMaj")) %>% unnest_longer(candidats) %>% 
  hoist(candidats,NomPsn="NomPsn",PrePsn="PrePsn",CivilitePsn="CivilitePsn") %>% unnest_longer(NomPsn) %>% 
  unnest_longer(PrePsn) %>% unnest_longer(CivilitePsn) 

communes <- communes %>%
  unnest_longer(Listes) %>% 
  hoist(Listes,NumListe="NumListe",CodNuaListe="CodNuaListe",NomListe="NomListe",LibLisExt="LibLisExt") %>% 
  unnest_longer(NumListe) %>% unnest_longer(CodNuaListe) %>% unnest_longer(NomListe) %>% unnest_longer(LibLisExt) %>% 
  hoist(Listes,candidats_liste="CandidatsListe") %>% unnest_longer(candidats_liste) %>% 
  hoist(candidats_liste,NumOrdCand="NumOrdCand",
        NomPsnL="NomPsn",PrePsnL="PrePsn",CivilitePsnL="CivilitePsn",TeteListe="TeteListe",CandidatEPCI="CandidatEPCI") %>%
  unnest_longer(NumOrdCand) %>%
  unnest_longer(NomPsnL) %>% unnest_longer(PrePsnL) %>% unnest_longer(CivilitePsnL) %>%
  unnest_longer(TeteListe) %>% unnest_longer(CandidatEPCI) 

communes <- communes %>%
  mutate(NomPsn = case_when(is.na(NomPsn) ~NomPsnL,
                            TRUE ~ NomPsn) ,
         PrePsn = case_when(is.na(PrePsn) ~ PrePsnL,
                            TRUE ~ PrePsn),
         CivilitePsn = case_when(is.na(CivilitePsn) ~ CivilitePsnL,
                                 TRUE ~ CivilitePsn) )
communes <- communes %>%
  select(-candidats,-candidats_id,-CandidatsMaj,-candidats_liste,-candidats_liste_id,-Listes,-Listes_id,
         -NomPsnL,-PrePsnL,-CivilitePsnL)
```